# Write apache environment variables and read them in php script

Tags: php, apache2, environment-variables

I have an index.php file that is running some script making mysql requests. For obvious security reason, i'd like to remove the mysql credentials (host, password, user, database) from this script and replace them with some apache environment variables.

I tried to create such variables in /etc/apache2/envvars using following line of code : `export MYSQL_USER='my_user'` and then I intend to get it back using getEnv php function like this : `getenv('MYSQL_USER')` but this returns nothing.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four steps :

- in /etc/apache2/envvars : `export MYVAR='value'`
- in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf : `PassEnv MYVAR`
- Restart apache
- in the php file located wherever apache2 is running: `echo $_SERVER['MYVAR'];`

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual host for Apache you could use

```
SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME value
```

and the get the value of this variable from your PHP code using

```
$variable = getenv('VARIABLE_NAME');
```

You can read more on SetEnv here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to store passwords in an environment variable, but you don't want other users to be able to read the password or key, you could follow the following steps (tested on Ubuntu 18.04):

- Create a file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/aws_key.conf`
- Change the ownership to root `sudo chown root:root /etc/apache2/conf-available/aws_key.conf`
- Change the file permission, so it is only readable for root `sudo chmod 600 /etc/apache2/conf-available/aws_key.conf`
- Put the password or key in the file, e.g. `SetEnv AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY abcdefg12345+-987654321`
- Enable the configuration file `sudo a2enconf aws_key`
- Restart Apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

This key is accessible in PHP via `$_SERVER['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']`.