# Unable To Set Environmental Variables in Apache

Tags: php, apache, variables, environment, setenv

I am trying to set environmental variables in Apache for a little added security, and access them with PHP.  I am using SetEnv inside of the VirtualHost directive in httpd.conf.  So in httpd.conf, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName "website.com"
    ServerAlias "www.website.com"
    SetEnv myDatabaseServer myserver.rds.amazonaws.com
    SetEnv myPort 3306
    SetEnv myUsername Username
    SetEnv myPassowrd Password
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =website.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.website.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Using a phpinfo() file, I am seeing none of my environmental variables listed, and I cannot access them in PHP using getenv either, so I am assuming that they are never even getting there.  I am always sure to restart httpd after changes.  I know I must be missing something small, but I rarely have to dig into config files, so I am hoping somebody can give me some insight or suggestions.  This is an AWS server.  I don't know if it matters, but the server is accessed by secure https. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I set this up on my development server, restarted Apache and the FPM module I'm using. `phpinfo()` doesn't show the extra variables, but PHP reads and echoes them just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write apache environment variables and read them in php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512271/write-apache-environment-variables-and-read-them-in-php-script)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried starting both Apache and FPM as you directed.  I still can't see the variable in phpinfo(), and PHP won't echo them out using getenv or $_SERVER.  I looked at your second link as well and could not get it to work either.  I am new to this, and feel like perhaps my VirtualHost is being overlooked altogether but am not sure why.  I keep stumbling across posts that say when using http, use port 80 and when using https, use 443 for VirtualHost.  My site is https, so do I need to have "<VirtualHost *:443>" somewhere?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I try to echo out the environmental variables I created, I just get a blank browser window.  No console errors either.  I tried to include a 443 VirtualHost as well, but then I got errors that the browser could not serve my files.  Still searching.

Comment: You could modify `.../bin/envvars` (in the same directory as apachectl).  This file is loaded when you start apache, setting up your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I had set up an auto-renewing SSL certificate when I set up this server.  I am new to all this web development, so I just figured EVERYTHING went into the httpd.conf file when it came to Apache.  Boy was I wrong.  When I created this certificate, about a dozen other config files were set up.  I went through them one by one and eventually found one named httpd-le-ssl.conf.  In this config, there was a VirtualHost setup listening to 443.  I put my environmental variables in there and, voila, it worked!

Thanks for the suggestions!